# How do I access static member of a class?

Tags: php, class, oop, static, member

I am trying to access static member of a class.

my class is:

```
class A
{
    public static $strName = 'A is my name'
    public function xyz()
    {
        ..
    }
    ..
}
//Since I have bunch of classes stored in an array
$x = array('A');
echo $x::$strName;
```

I am getting error while printing. How can I print **'A is my name'**

Comment: I think you want an instance of class A in the array not the character 'A' (which doesn't have a static member called strName)

Comment: well i have a list of class in a array which i have to iterate throug

Comment: Static member call via method has been choosed better than reflection.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If `A` is a class, you can access it directly via `A::$strName`.

```
class A {
    public static $strName = 'A is my name';
}

echo A::$strName; // outputs "A is my name"
```

#### Update:

Depending on what you have inside your array, whether its what I like to define as *class objects* or *class literals* could be a factor. I distinguish these two terms by,

```
$objClasses = array(new A(), new B()); // class objects
$myClasses = array('A','B');           // class literals
```

If you go the class literals approach, then using a `foreach` loop with PHP5.2.8 I am given a syntax error when using the [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

```
foreach ($myClasses as $class) {
     echo $class::$strName;
  //syntax error, unexpected '::', expecting ',' or ';'
}
```

So then I thought about using the class objects approach, but the only way I could actually output the static variable was with an instance of an object and using the `self` keyword like so,

```
class A {
    public static $strName = 'A is my name';

    function getStatic() {
        return self::$strName;
    }
}

class B {
    public static $strName = 'B is my name';

    function getStatic() {
        return self::$strName;
    }
}
```

And then invoke that method when iterating,

```
foreach($objClasses as $obj) {
    echo $obj->getStatic();
}
```

Which at that point why declare the variable `static` at all? It defeats the whole idea of accessing a variable without the need to instantiate an object.

In short, once we have more information as to what you would like to do, we can then go on and provide better answers.

Comment: well i have a list of class in a array which i have to iterate throug so do have to access using array

Comment: I am not quite following, what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Looks right. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php. This is what I was trying to remember.

Comment: I even tried the example given in but its giving me error. I got PHP version 5.2

Comment: @KoolKabin I am using PHP 5.2.8 and it ran fine on my browser. Can you actually post what you are trying to do? It seems what you are trying to do is a bit messy and with some more information could be cleaned up a bit. Do you have an array of classes?, ie. `array(new A(), new B())`

Answer (score 10):

If you want a working version for PHP5.2, you can use [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to access the static property of a class.

```
class A {
    static $strName= '123';
}

$lstClass = array('A');
    
foreach ($lstClass as $value) {
    $c = new ReflectionClass($value);
    echo $c->getStaticPropertyValue('strName');
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/HFJCW

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error with missing semicolon and because it is an array you need to access the index of 0, or else it would be trying to call class 'Array'.

```
class A
{
    public static $strName = 'A is my name';

    public function xyz()
    {
        // left blank and removed syntax error
    }
}
$x = array('A');
echo $x[0]::$strName;
```

Should fix it.

**UPDATE**

If you want to iterate over an array to call a class variable:

```
$x = array('A', 'B');
foreach ($x as $class) {
     echo $class::$strName;
}
```

Not sure why you would want that, but there you go. And this has been tested, no errors were thrown, valid response of `A is my name` was received.

**EDIT**

Apparently this only works under PHP 5.3

Comment: This was directed @ a deleted comment as an fyi: I tested it via the `php -a` cli tool. It worked great. I did modify the code to remove the `...` as they would need to be removed to not cause syntax errors.  And the `B` class will need to be created for the **UPDATE** section to work properly.

Comment: Nevermind ideone.com is using the PHP5.2 and it works fine under PHP5.3

Answer (score 1):

From inside a class and want to access a static data member of its own you can also use 
**static::** 
instead of 
**self::**

Answer (score 0):

I do find next one simple solution but don't know whether its good one or not.

My soln is:

```
eval('return '.$x[0].'::$strName;');
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `eval` much, it can be evil.

Comment: can it be treated as evil if we are going to use only the fixed predefined commands

Comment: Honestly, as a personal preference I wouldn't even use it with predefined commands. No, it shouldn't be *evil* to do it the way you are doing it, but I know there are better solutions.

Comment: yes, it is extremely problematic to use that. For example, if the class is not found, this will just create  a fatal error, which will make the hole script stop without any possibility of catching the error. If you were using reflection, it will launch an exception that can be catched.

Comment: thnx for suggestion. so then reflection method is the better one than others. is it?