# the correct way to access a static arrays from a static function inside a PHP class

Tags: php, class, static, member

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do i access static member of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818333/how-do-i-access-static-member-of-a-class)

I have this class. In its `createNew` function I refer to `$reftbArr = tc_group::$tblFields;`.

I have many classes similar to this class a couple of times. They have the same methods and variables but of course the class name is different.

How is the best way in the function `createNew` to access `tc_group::$tblFields;` but not have the hardcoded class name?

```
<?php
class tc_group {
    public $id;
    public $password;
    private static $tableName = "tc_group";

    public static $tblFields = array(
        ':id'        => array('value' => '','required' => 0),
        ':password'  => array('value' => '','required' => 0)
    );

   public static function createNew($link , $tblfields){
    $reftbArr = tc_group::$tblFields;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: +1, to negate one of the downvotes. Trying to make the world a better place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$tableFields = self::$tblFields;

print_r($tableFields);

Answer (score 2):

You can use self for example: `self::$variable`

You can use static for example: `static::$variable`

The difference is that self will access the current class it is used in (ignoring inheritance), static will obey inheritance.

**Extended Answer**

> I have this same class a couple of times. they have the same methods and vars but of course the class name is different.

That sounds like it needs refactoring. In which case create an "abstract class" which defines all the properties and methods defined by the other classes and remove them from the other classes (as they are now in the abstract class). Then extend the abstract class to create the separate classes as needed that contain ONLY WHAT CHANGES in them.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the static keyword [`self`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

```
public static function createNew($link , $tblfields){
    $reftbArr = self::$tblFields;
}
```