# Undefined variable in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I created an array in User model and a function which return this array. Laravel return Undefined variable error. Model code:

```
private $groups = [
        '033-philosophy' => "phil",
        '035.01-lit' => "lit",
        '035.01-lang' => "lang",
        '034' => "culture"
    ];

    public static function getGroupsList() {
        return $groups;
    }
```

Call function in controller:

```
$groups = \App\User::getGroupsList();
return view('orders.create', compact('groups'));
```

Comment: should not you use ```$this->groups```?

Comment: No, i need to use it without creating an object

Comment: then define variable as static - ```private static $groups;``` and access it via ```return self::$groups;``` - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3818347/12396017

Comment: Oh, it works. Thank you!